# TableToGrid initially ugly. Then it formats correctly. How to get hide table until everything is ready

Tags: jqgrid-asp.net

I like using jqGrid and TableToGrid especially.  Getting Json data is nice as well, and I use  that functionality in a couple of views in my asp.net MVC4 application, however, the one page where I have jqGrid TableToGrid.  The only thing is, when you first load the page or when you refresh a page with a table to grid page on it, The table looks ugly, and then it stabilizes.  Is there a way I can hide the table or show a loading screen until the thing is fully ready to view...
I know regular jqGrid has a loading text option, but that is only when your table is being loaded via ajax...
You can put a load dialog over the grid... But I have my loading dialog pop up on document.ready and the ugly looking grid is still there initially.  Maybe there is a way I can hide the table earlier than $(document).ready ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can put your entire grid into a div with visibility:hidden or display:none and just show that div with jquery in document.ready.

**[Update]**
You may show div in jqgrid's gridComplete event. According to their documentation "*This fires after all the data is loaded into the grid and all other processes are complete. Also the event fires independent from the datatype parameter and after sorting paging and etc.*"

Check their wiki for more info http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events

Comment: I would, but on $(Document).ready the grid is still pretty ugly...  I was hoping there was some kind of jqGrid-TableToGrid-finished-loading event I could latch onto to hide until everything is ready.  I need an event before $(document).ready and after tableToGrid loads and beautifies my ugly Html table.